# Unclear purpose of code?

Tags: c, ipv4, bit-fields, packets, raw-sockets

I am learning about raw socket programming in Linux and during a tutorial I noticed a coincidence with this code:

```
struct ipheader {
 unsigned char      iph_ihl:5, iph_ver:4; //<--------------These
 unsigned char      iph_tos;
 unsigned short int iph_len;
 unsigned short int iph_ident;
 unsigned char      iph_flag;
 unsigned short int iph_offset;
 unsigned char      iph_ttl;
 unsigned char      iph_protocol;
 unsigned short int iph_chksum;
 unsigned int       iph_sourceip;
 unsigned int       iph_destip;
};
```

`iph_ver` holds the IP version which will be 4, and `iph_ihl` holds the header length which will be set to 5. Since header length is described in 4 byte words the actual header length comes out to be 5×4=20 bytes. 20 bytes is the minimum length. With that being said I am curious if the bit fields in this structure, set for `iph_ver` and `iph_ihl`, are specifically 4 and 5 because it will be IPv4 and the IP header will be 20 bytes in length. However I am unsure how their bit fields would have any effect or correlation on their value. Any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Link to code: http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html

Comment: It is bit fields.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But don't bitfields determine the size in bits and only in bits? They don't determine the actual value of that data, just how much room it has. Or am I missing something fundamental about bitfields and/or how version and header length work in ip headers?

Comment: That's odd though, IHL is supposed to be a 4 bit field.

Comment: @Arthuer Hames  Here for example  iph_ihl:5 declares a bit field of type unsigned character that occupies 5 bits.

Comment: Somehow I don't think you copied it right. An `unsigned char` does not have a total of 9 bits in it.

Comment: They are not connected to values they are just specifying how many bits they occupy and to limit the max values

Comment: See [Wikipedia's IPv4 header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure) description. IHL is just a 4-bit number (0-15) saying how many 32-bit words are in the header. (So IHL*32bits = size of header, and IHL>=5 so the header size ranges from 20 bytes to 60 bytes.)

Comment: I edited my question to include a link to the tutorial.

Comment: @e0k Oh, okay that is much clearer. I misinterpreted it to mean that since the first byte was `45` you then multiply version and length because it said `’45’ corresponds to the first two fields in the header ie  ‘4’ corresponds to the IP version and ‘5’ corresponds to the header length. Since header length is described in 4 byte words so actual header length comes out to be 5×4=20 bytes.`. Sorry, I'm slow sometimes. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code fragment from this tutorial is actually wrong!

Here is a correct definition for the IP packet header:

```
/*
 * Structure of an internet header, naked of options.
 *
 * We declare ip_len and ip_off to be short, rather than u_short
 * pragmatically since otherwise unsigned comparisons can result
 * against negative integers quite easily, and fail in subtle ways.
 */
struct ip {
#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN 
    u_char  ip_hl:4,        /* header length */
            ip_v:4;         /* version */
#endif
#if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN 
    u_char  ip_v:4,         /* version */
            ip_hl:4;        /* header length */
#endif
    u_char  ip_tos;         /* type of service */
    short   ip_len;         /* total length */
    u_short ip_id;          /* identification */
    short   ip_off;         /* fragment offset field */
#define IP_DF 0x4000        /* dont fragment flag */
#define IP_MF 0x2000        /* more fragments flag */
    u_char  ip_ttl;         /* time to live */
    u_char  ip_p;           /* protocol */
    u_short ip_sum;         /* checksum */
    struct  in_addr ip_src,ip_dst;  /* source and dest address */
};
```

As you can see, both `ip_hl` and `ip_v` are 4 bit wide bitfields.  The actual names of the fields do not matter, just their position in the packet header.

They are defined in a different order depending on the platform because the compiler allocates bitfields differently depending on endianness. This behavior is actually not specified in the C Standard, but seems to be consistent across platforms.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think in an effort to avoid similar occurrences I'm going to find a new tutorial.